# Should I raise exceptions in Equals() and GetHashCode() if true comparison needs an IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

One of my classes has a horrible requirement that resolving one of it's fields requires a service to be brought in by Dependency Injection, which is obviously not possible in a model in the standard `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` calls. (Yes, I'd prefer it not to, bad practice etc, but I'm kind of stuck with it as a business requirement, unfortunately)

I can solve this by creating a Comparer class using `IEqualityComparer<T>`, but this leaves me with the default `Object.Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` being implemented, which may give misleading results when called.

As the presence of the `IEqualityComparer` is kind of 'hidden' unless you know about it, is it reasonable practice to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode` to return an exception to say that comparisons should use the Comparer? (Maybe just an Assert so that it only dies in debug/tests)

Comment: The default behaviour of `Equals` (reference comparison) is not suitable?

Comment: Not really - the main reason for this is that we're comparing an object retrieved from DB with an object with fields re-calculated with current DB values.

I could test all fields apart from the problem one, but the issue is that it's something that changes over time based on external data, so it's the one most likely to become not-equal

Comment: why is the injection not possible in "standard equals"? If you inject the comparer to the constructor, you should be able to use it in your `Equals`.

Comment: as creating models doesn't go via DI - it's not registered in the ASP.NET DI container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing an exception like `NotSupportedException` is better than giving an incorrect answer, although since this is a class, arguably reference equality would suffice as the default, just using the external equality comparer for the custom functionality. But if that is going to cause confusion (in particular with people accidentally using the default API when they should be using the custom one); I wouldn't hesitate. The main problem you'll see is things like `Contains` checks blowing up, since classes aren't *often* used as dictionary keys.

As for only doing this in DEBUG builds... well, if it is wrong: it is wrong. If there's a scenario you aren't currently testing but that is used in prod, IMO it is better to become aware of that fact than to *not*. Although perhaps you might use an environment variable it similar to disable it in case you can't conveniently deploy a fixed build at short notice.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm comparing two mutable objects, I would expect reference equality to be used by default. For records or structs I would expect value equality. For immutable objects I would probably expect value equality, but it depend a bit more on the context.

So I would only throw exceptions or use Debug.Asserts if I was sure reference equality is never the correct thing to use. And in that case I would be extra careful to document and highlight this unexpected behavior.

I would prefer exceptions over a `Debug.Assert`, since testing is usually done on release builds. And you want to find and fix these kinds of problems, since they most likely indicate a programming bug. There is also `Trace.Assert`, but I would probably not recommend it since it will make things like automated testing more difficult.